# Cloudformation to create EKS Managed Node Group with Encrypted Volume

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks

I have a CloudFormation template that creates a Managed Node Group:

```
 NodeGroup:
    Type: AWS::EKS::Nodegroup
    Properties: 
      ClusterName: !Ref Cluster
      InstanceTypes:
        - !Ref NodeInstanceClass
      NodegroupName: ng-0
      NodeRole: !GetAtt NodeInstanceRole.Arn
      ScalingConfig: 
        MinSize: !Ref ClusterMinSize
        DesiredSize: !Ref ClusterDesiredSize
        MaxSize: !Ref ClusterMaxSize
      Subnets: 
        - !Ref AppSubnetID1
        - !Ref AppSubnetID2
```

**Question:** Is there a way to have the Nodes creates with their **EBS volume encrypted**?

Possibly encrypted AMIs available somewhere?

Comment: With normal nodes, switching default encryption on your account on works... I haven't tried managed node groups yet (we need soms sysctl settings)

Answer (score 1):

Enable [default encryption for EBS volumes on your AWS account's EC2 settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSEncryption.html#encryption-by-default). It results in all EBS volumes being created encrypted by default.

The other option is to use a [launch template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-templates.html):

```
  NodeGroup:
    Type: AWS::EKS::Nodegroup
    Properties: 
      ClusterName: !Ref Cluster
      InstanceTypes:
        - !Ref NodeInstanceClass
      NodegroupName: ng-0
      LaunchTemplate:
        Version: !GetAtt NodeLaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
        Id: !Ref NodeLaunchTemplate
      NodeRole: !GetAtt NodeInstanceRole.Arn
      ScalingConfig: 
        MinSize: !Ref ClusterMinSize
        DesiredSize: !Ref ClusterDesiredSize
        MaxSize: !Ref ClusterMaxSize
      Subnets: 
        - !Ref AppSubnetID1
        - !Ref AppSubnetID2

  NodeLaunchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateData:
        BlockDeviceMappings:
          - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
            Ebs:
              VolumeSize: !Ref NodeVolumeSize
              VolumeType: gp3
              Encrypted: true
              DeleteOnTermination: true
        KeyName: !Ref KeyName
        NetworkInterfaces:
        - DeviceIndex: 0
          Groups:
          - !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      LaunchTemplateName: !Sub ${Cluster}-${NodeGroupName}-template
```

Answer (score 0):

Based upon EKS we need to make encrypted PV/PVCs for k8s cluster.

This online tutorial has the steps:

https://prabhatsharma.in/blog/using-encrypted-ebs-volumes-on-kubernetes-with-aws/

This will only show you how to do it in k8s though.

We need to adapt this to EKS Cloudformation template.

We can do this by using the relevant CloudFormation tags for the EKS Cluster encryption provider here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-eks-cluster-encryptionconfig.html

You will need to set the following parameters:

```
Type: AWS::EKS::Cluster
Properties: 
  EncryptionConfig: 
    Provider: 
      Provider
    Resources: 
      - String
  Name: String
  ResourcesVpcConfig: 
    ResourcesVpcConfig
  RoleArn: String
  Version: String
```

Note this is done in the AWS::EKS::Cluster not the NodeGroup via EncryptionConfig.

Properties
Provider
The encryption provider for the cluster.

Required: No

Type: Provider

Resources
Specifies the resources to be encrypted. The only supported value is "secrets".

Required: No

Type: List of String

Comment: That will only enccrypt the secrets in the etcd. It does not affect the EBS volumes...